# Does Node Child Process Spawn Run on Multi Core CPU?

Tags: node.js, child-process

When I call .spawn to make a new child process in Node.js, does this take advantage of multi-core CPUs?

Reference: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a new process will be created and managed by your OS. That new process can be executed in parallel to the main process as long as your computer has at least 2 virtual CPU cores.

Comment: what happens if you have 1 core and you spawn child process

Comment: The same thing that happens when you have multiple cores. The operating system schedules the execution of the processes amongst N cores, which in your case, would mean that all processes are being executed by 1 core.

Comment: so you still get some benefit? if you have one core, and you create clusters, then processor will make them run in parallel ( even one task is long running? ) . I read somewhere intel processors do virtual core which let even single core act like multi core.

Comment: If the processes can be executed in parallel by the processor, then yes, you will get the benefit.